# Singleton with AsyncLocal vs Scope Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpcontext

I looked at how HttpContext being created in .NET Core. Then I found that there is a class called `HttpContextFactory` which create and assign `HttpContext` object into a `HttpContext` property of `HttpContextAccessor` class. And to use HttpContext object in our code, we inject IHttpContextAccessor to the constructor of the class that needs the object.

When I looked at the implementation of HttpContextAccessor, apparently its HttpContext property gets the HttpContext object value from a private `AsyncLocal` variable and later on HttpContextAccessor is registered as **Singleton**.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System.Threading;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
{
    public class HttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private static AsyncLocal<HttpContextHolder> _httpContextCurrent = new AsyncLocal<HttpContextHolder>();

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get
            {
                return  _httpContextCurrent.Value?.Context;
            }
            set
            {
                var holder = _httpContextCurrent.Value;
                if (holder != null)
                {
                    // Clear current HttpContext trapped in the AsyncLocals, as its done.
                    holder.Context = null;
                }

                if (value != null)
                {
                    // Use an object indirection to hold the HttpContext in the AsyncLocal,
                    // so it can be cleared in all ExecutionContexts when its cleared.
                    _httpContextCurrent.Value = new HttpContextHolder { Context = value };
                }
            }
        }

        private class HttpContextHolder
        {
            public HttpContext Context;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm curious, what is the benefit of doing it this way instead of using a **Scope** service? It seems to me both would make the object available within a request scope.

If it's a scope service, I reckon the HttpContextAccessor will look something like this

```
using System.Threading;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
{
    public class HttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private HttpContextHolder _httpContextCurrent;

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get
            {
                return  _httpContextCurrent?.Context;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    _httpContextCurrent = new HttpContextHolder { Context = value };
                }
            }
        }

        private class HttpContextHolder
        {
            public HttpContext Context;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as scope service

```
services.TryAddScope<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages for each approach, so that I'll understand when to use Singleton with AsyncLocal or Scope when creating a library for my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as it is a singleton, the resolved `IHttpContextAccessor` instance could be holded permanently by a singleton service and work properly, while it could cause problems if a singleton service resolves a scoped `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, if you look at this file https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs. `IHttpContextAccessor` is registered as singleton. That works because they use `AsyncLocal` to store the HttpContext object inside `HttpContextAccessor` class. I'm asking what's the difference if instead IHttpContextAccessor is registered as scoped and AsyncLocal is not used to store the HttpContext inside HttpContextAccessor class.

Comment: `DefaultHttpContextFactory` itself is not registered as `Singleton` but is registered `Transient` as you can see in this file https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/f3f9a1cdbcd06b298035b523732b9f45b1408461/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/WebHostBuilder.cs#L284. This class is the one that responsible to set the value of HttpContext.

Comment: If what you meant was, this class is set to singleton so that whenever we create our own singleton class in our project, we can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` there. It kinda makes sense :) But may I ask the scenarios on when we need to access `IHttpContextAccessor` from a singleton class in our web project?

Comment: As for some stateful services that may have some methods that must be called within a request (which means the object has a singleton lifetime while a method calling is scoped), it is probably useful to make it one service rather than a scoped service depending on a singleton store service.

Comment: @Alsien could it be possible that since IServiceProvider in asp.net core does not allow scoped service injection inside singleton so thats why HttpContextAccessor was made singleton with asynclocal rather than Scoped as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I guess one of the reasons could be that Asp.Net Core IServiceProvider does not allow Scoped Dependency to be injected inside Singleton class. That could be a major decision behind that. If things would have been scoped as you suggested then all the classes using it may have to be scoped. But interestingly enough once the request is served the HTTPContext becomes null.